# Offline slideshow on a Chromebook

Tags: chromebook, google-plus

Can Chromebooks do offline slideshows from Google Plus albums?

If not, what other approaches can be used to show a slideshow offline from a Chromebook?

(the scenario I am thinking of is taking a Chromebook to show pictures to an older relative who is in a retirement home with no internet connection)

Answer (score 2):

The [Google+ Photos](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/google+-photos/efjnaogkjbogokcnohkmnjdojkikgobo) app caches your most recent photos for offline viewing. It is not perfect as there are no explicit controls to set albums or photos as being accessible offline. It does do slide shows so depending on it's default caching mode, it might work for you.

Answer (score 0):

No, By default, Chrome OS does not possess this feature. There is a possibility that such an app to achieve this is available on the chrome store, but I wouldn't know if there is.

The best solution would be to actually download the photos you want to show to your chromebook's hard drive, and then display them in the photo viewer application installed onto the computer. I cannot recall if this photo viewer has a automatic slideshow feature, as I have not used chrome OS in a while, but it seems likely that it's photo viewer would have such a feature as most OS photo viewers do.